# Modifying a pre-existing taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a theme that registers a flat taxonomy of tags and I need to convert it into a hierarchical taxonomy. Is there any way to modify a preexisting taxonomy (without editing my theme's files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a hook called [`register_taxonomy_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/) that should get you what you want. The [constructor for the `WP_Taxonomy`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_taxonomy/__construct/) object calls the method [`set_props`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_taxonomy/set_props/) which calls this hook very early on. Here's a quick (but untested) example:

```php
add_filter(
    'register_taxonomy_args',
    static function (array $args, string $taxonomy, array $object_type) {
        if ('my-taxonomy' === $taxonomy) {
            $args['hierarchical'] = true;
        }
        return $args;
    },
    10,
    3
);
```